# Facing issue with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context

Tags: apache, exception, servlets, velocity

I'm a new learner velocity. I am trying to display the template in HTML format by writing a servlet for that. The following is my servlet code

```
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
              VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
              try {
                velocityEngine.init();
                Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate("./src/Menu.txt");

              VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
              context.put( "special-1", "./src/special-1.txt" );
              context.put( "special-2", "./src/special-2.txt" );
              context.put( "special-3", "./src/special-3.txt" );
              StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
              template.merge(context, writer);
              out.println(writer);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

And following is the stack trace im getting...

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.velocity.context.Context
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
        ... 21 more
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the velocity-version.jar to your server classpath, you can put it in the **lib** folder of your tomcat server, or you can put this jar in the **WEB-INF/lib** folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Download [velocity-1.7](http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache//velocity/engine/1.7/velocity-1.7.zip)  jar and add in to eclipse Deployment Assembly then restart the server.

Comment: Fixed link: http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/velocity/engine/1.7/velocity-1.7.zip